# Implementing Naive Bayes text categorization but I keep getting zeros

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, text-classification, naivebayes

I am using Naive Bayes for text categorization this is how I created the initial weights for each term in the specified category:

- term1:number of times term 1 exists/number of documents in categoryA
- term2:number of times term 2 exists/number of documents in categoryA
- term3:number of times term 3 exists/number of documents in categoryA
- term1:number of times term 1 exists/number of documents in categoryB
- term2:number of times term 2 exists/number of documents in categoryB
- term3:number of times term 3 exists/number of documents in categoryB

with the new test document I adjust the weights based on whether the term exists in the test document or not:

- term1: exists in the test document so I use the same weight for categoryA_term1 as above
- term2: does NOT exist in the test document so I use the 1-weight for categoryA_term2
- term3: does NOT exist in the test document so I use the 1-weight for categoryA_term3
- term1: exists in the test document so I use the same weight for categoryB_term1 as above
- term2: does NOT exist in the test document so I use the 1-weight for categoryB_term2
- term3: exists in the test document so I use the same weight for categoryB_term2 as above

Then I multiply the weights for each category. 
This works when I create dummy train/test documents of one sentence each but when I implement real documents for train/test documents I keep getting zero when I multiple it all together. Is this because the probabilities are so small that after multiplying so many small numbers, python just converges to zero??
I am so stuck and I just keep running into the same zero issue :( I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Make sure you don't multiply by any zero terms. The method you have described could easily result in weights of zero.

Comment: Well I check whether the term exists in the test_document and if the term does exists I give it the weight that I had computed earlier from the training set, if the weight is not in the test document then I give it 1-weight. I ignore terms that I have not already given a weight to, i.e terms that do not exist in my bag of words. So a zero term shouldn't exist. I also just double checked and I get no zeros in any of my weights.

Comment: You also need to make sure the weight isn't 1 because `1 - weight` would be zero. That said, it probably is an underflow problem cause by multiplying too many tiny numbers. @DouglasZare has provided an excellent way to address that problem.

Comment: I don't have a 1 for the weight either. Looking into the underflow problem, should I then use logs as well as the conditional probability he put up? I'm asking you as well as below in case he doesn't see my message. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but do the probability calculations the way he suggested.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for your help. The log problem was my issue, and my conditional probability had (k+1)/(n+len(bag of words)) instead of (k+1)/(n+2), not sure if this would make much of a difference, since it would be consistent everywhere but I changed it anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ed Cottrell commented, you need to consider what happens if you encounter a word that is not in the documents in a category. You can avoid multiplying by 0 by using [Laplace smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing). If you see a word in k out of n documents in a category, you assign the conditional probability (k+1)/(n+2) or (k+a)/(n+2a) to that word given the category.

Instead of taking a product of many small numbers, it is standard to compute the logarithm of the product.

```
log x*y = log x + log y
log(P(a0|c) * P(a1|c) * ... * P(ak|c))
    = log P(a0|c) + log P(a1|c) + ... + log P(ak|c)
```

Then you have a sum of numbers that are not so small. Avoid using log 0. You can exponentiate afterwards if necessary, but usually you just translate your decision threshold into a condition on the logarithm.

Comment: So then I should use the conditional probability AND convert to logs? Thanks in advance

Comment: You always use conditional probabilities in a naive Bayes classifier. You should use Laplace smoothing and use logs.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try this out, will update! Thank you, I hope I do this correctly and it works *crossed fingers*

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!!! How do I vote that you answered on here? I want to give you credit for it. You don't know how relieved I am, I feel so happy haha

Comment: @hope288: I'm happy to have helped. There should be a checkmark you can click to the left of this answer if you want to mark it as accepted.

Comment: after the summation of the logs are computed do I multiply or add the log of ((the number of documents in that category)/number of documents) to the result so that I can get the final probability of the new document being categorized as 'a'? I just want to know whether the 0.6 should be added to the summed logs (inbrackets but it's originalformula so nologsshwn) or multiplied::::                                                                            P(a | x)  =  [4/6 * (1-4/6) * (1-3/6) * 3/6 * 2/6] * P(a) / P(x)
 = [0.67 * 0.33 * 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.33] * 0.6 / P(x) = 0.11 / P(x)

Comment: I think that we add since they are all probabilities, but just wanted to check with you. Thanks!

Comment: @hope288: You add the log of 0.6. It's like one of the conditional probabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response